# p values without leading zero and introduced with smaller than sign in kableextra

Tags: r, kableextra

I like to visualize a data frame in which a column includes p values with decimal places and without leading zero with kableExtra. Unfortunately, as soon as a value without leading zero is introduced with a smaller than sign, a greater than sign appears in the table at the end of this value. The problem does not exist, if the `escape = FALSE` command is removed. But since `escape = FALSE` is needed for other reasons (e.g. for footnotes or italics), I would be grateful for any explanation on how to avoid the greater than sign.

The following example illustrates the problem.

```
df <- data.frame(x=c("okA","okB","okC","problem", "okD"), 
                 my_pvalue=c("0.08", ".43", "<0.001", "<.001", "0.01"), 
                 y=c(1,2,3,4,5))

df %>%
  kableExtra::kable(escape = FALSE, 
                    digits = c(0, 3, 0))%>%
  kable_classic()
```

Comment: How about replacing `<` with `&lt;`?

Comment: this works in the example. As the p values result out of the `format.pval(my_pvalue, digits = 2, eps = 0.001, nsmall = 3)` command, it would be nice if there was an elegant way to handle this as well.

Comment: How about writing a wrapper function to replace any `<`s in the output from `format.pval()` with `&lt;`?  the call the wrapper function rather than `format.pval`. If this was an important feature of any proposed solution, it should really have been mentioned in the problem specification.

Comment: '<' and '>' are special characters for HTML. You could transform them into '&lt;' and '&gt;' before creating a kable. E.g. `df %>% transform(my_pvalue = gsub('<', '&lt;', my_pvalue)) %>% kable(escape = FALSE) %>% kable_classic()`

Answer (score 0):

to get the question answered:

the comments of @DarrenTsai and @Limey lead to a solution.

for those who also like to use custom made footnotes: insert the command `%>% mutate(my_pvalue = gsub('<', '&lt;', my_pvalue))` in your code in a place before working with the `footnote_marker_***` command, as the `footnote_marker_***` command is accompanied by html '<' (and '>').